# Creating a list from a set of values in a heavily nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create a list out of the timestamps in this nested dictionary, but I'm having difficulty.

```
{
    '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob',
    'builds': [
        {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571731200315
        },
        {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571731020310
        },
        {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571730995706
        }, {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571730900316
        }, {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571730600313
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried the following, but as the second value itself consists of a nested dictionary, it's not parsing the timestamps as I would like:

```
dictList=[]
for key, value in dict.items():
    dictList.append([value])
print (dictList[1])
```

The output from this attempt is the following:

```
[
    [
        {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571731200315
        },
        {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571731020310
        },
        {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571730995706
        },
        {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571730900316
        },
        {
            '_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun',
            'timestamp': 1571730600313
        }
    ]
]
```

How can I drill down into the nested contents and retrieve only the timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dict = {'_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob', 'builds': [{'_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun', 'timestamp': 1571731200315}, {'_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun', 'timestamp': 1571731020310}, {'_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun', 'timestamp': 1571730995706}, {'_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun', 'timestamp': 1571730900316}, {'_class': 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun', 'timestamp': 1571730600313}]}

timestamps = []
for i in dict['builds']:
    timestamps.append(i['timestamp'])

print(timestamps)
```

I am not clear on this is what you want, but this can get all the timestamps into a list.

Comment: Presumably the user has a reason why he is using `.items()` otherwise he would have just iterated the list.  Though items is for dict, im curious if the OP was trying something specific or just doesnt know how to walk lists.